# If a, b belong to S prove that ab belongs to S

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question states that there is a set of real numbers S such that 1 belongs to S and if a, b belong to S, then a-b belongs to S and 1/a, 1/b will both belong to S. Prove that ab belongs to S.

I have been thinking about this question for some time and I was able to do was prove that if a, b were integers then they belong to S. I am stuck right now. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure I follow the rules.  Since $1\in S$ we must have $0=1-1\in S$, yes?  But $\frac 10$ can't be in $S$ so...

Comment: @lulu Simple possible fix: Require that $a,b$ are distinct.

Comment: @Arthur  Sure, or (even simpler) just say that $a \in S, a\neq 0 \implies \frac 1a\in S$.  Your method doesn't quickly lead to $0\in S$...but of course I have no idea what the OP (or their source) intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave edge cases (e.g "what if $n$ is $0$") and in-between steps as 'exercises'. We can make $0$ trivially, and therefore $\pm n$ from $n$. $n^2$ from $n$ as follows:

$n\to \frac{1}{n-1},\frac{1}{n}\to\frac{1}{n^2-n}\to n^2$

So we can make $(\frac{a-b}{ab})^2,\frac{1}{a^2},\frac{1}{b^2}$. Thus $\frac{a^2-2ab+b^2}{a^2b^2}-\frac{a^2}{a^2b^2}-\frac{b^2}{a^2b^2}$ is doable, so we can make $\frac{2ab}{a^2b^2}$ so it's not too hard to make $ab$ from there.

This question was kinda hard in that it's really easy to accidentally assume the question in order to solve it.